# function vs lambda statement

Tags: python

Lambda is confusing me a little, here is what I've got :

```
lmb = lambda d: datetime.datetime.strptime(d["Date[G]"]+"-"+d["Time[G]"], "%d-%b-%Y-%H:%M:%S.%f")
```

if I write a function like this :

```
def time(d):
    t = datetime.datetime.strptime(d["Date[G]"]+"-"+d["Time[G]"], "%d-%b-%Y-%H:%M:%S.%f")
    return t.strftime("%d-%b-%Y-%H")
```

I can `return t.strftime("%d-%b-%Y-%H")`.

Can I embed a somethine like `t.strftime("%d-%b-%Y-%H")` in my lambda statement ?

**EDIT**

I`ve tried this :

```
lmb = lambda d: datetime.datetime.strptime(d["Date[G]"]+"-"+d["Time[G]"], "%d-%b-%Y-%H:%M:%S.%f").strftime("%d-%b-%Y-%H")
```

but it returns :

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'

which doesn't happen using the function ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure:

```
lmb = lambda d: datetime.datetime.strptime(d["Date[G]"]+"-"+d["Time[G]"], "%d-%b-%Y-`%H:%M:%S.%f").strftime("%d-%b-%Y-%H")
```

But it pretty quickly just makes sense to use a function.

Comment: I could use a function but I`m using the lambda statement this way : for k, g in itertools.groupby(csvReader, key = lmb)

Comment: @Fingertwist I copied/pasted your new version, and I don't get the error. You can pass the function to groupby, functions and lambda are the exact same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do it like this:

```
lmb = lambda d: datetime.datetime.strptime(d["Date[G]"]+"-"+d["Time[G]"], "%d-%b-%Y-%H:%M:%S.%f").strftime("%d-%b-%Y-%H")
```

I tested this on Python 2.7:

```
>>> lmb = lambda d: datetime.datetime.strptime(d["Date[G]"]+"-"+d["Time[G]"], "%d-%b-%Y-%H:%M:%S.%f").strftime("%d-%b-%Y-%H")
>>> lmb({"Date[G]": "22-Apr-2012", "Time[G]": "07:23:24.123"})
'22-Apr-2012-07'
```